# Efficient text scroller

Tags: javascript

I wrote this small test. I would love to know if it's possible to achieve the same result in a more "efficient" way. Before any moderator closes this question, it's not subjective because my definition of efficient here means less lines of code and less memory usage.

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/YsjLp/

And here is the JavaScript code:

```
var position = 0;
var divToEdit = document.getElementById('here');

function executeIt(){
    setInterval(function(){moveIt()},300);  
}

function moveIt(){
    var textToInsert = '';
    var textLength = 10;

    for (var i = 0; i <= textLength; i++) {     
        
        if(i == position){                      
            textToInsert += '[-]';      
        }else{
            textToInsert += '-';    
        }       
    };  

    if(position == textLength){
        position = 0;
    }else{
        position += 1;
    }
    
    divToEdit.innerHTML = textToInsert;
}   

executeIt();
```

Comment: Is there even a question here?

Comment: @remyabel yes, the question is, could the above code be rewritten in a more efficient way, efficient defined in the question body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you define efficient to be "less lines of code", here it is:

```
function moveIt(){
    var textToInsert = '';
    var textLength = 10;

    for (var i = 0; i <= textLength; i++)
        textToInsert+= (i==position)?'[-]':'-';
    (position==textLength)?position=0:position++;
    divToEdit.innerHTML = textToInsert;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/YsjLp/3/

Comment: Fair enough, a good use of ternary operators, i would love to see both benchmarked, i'll check and see, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Some tips:

- Use `const` and `let` over `var`, they are simply better.
- Readability pretty much always trumps 'efficiency'
- Use `textContent` if you are not actually inserting HTML
- You can use parameters to make your code more flexible

```js
const targetDiv = document.getElementById('target');
const chars = '[-]';
const bgChars = '-';
const length = 20;
const intervalMs = 200;

let position = 0;
const moveCharsInText = (
  targetElement,
  charsToMove,
  backgroundChars,
  sectionCount
) => {
  let textToInsert = '';

  for (let i = 0; i < sectionCount; i++) {
    if (i === position) {
      textToInsert += charsToMove;
    } else {
      textToInsert += backgroundChars;
    }
  }

  position++;
  if (position >= sectionCount) {
    position = 0;
  }

  targetElement.textContent = textToInsert;
};

const start = () => {
  setInterval(() => {
    moveCharsInText(targetDiv, chars, bgChars, length);
  }, intervalMs);
};

start();
```

```html
<div id="target"></div>
```